# How many magmas exist on $n$-element set

Tags: abstract-algebra, latin-square, magma

It is clear that we can make $n^{n^2}$ Latin squares (I think that this is no real Latin square, but I don't know how to name it) for $n$-element set, but I have heard that some magmas will be isomorpic and the number of magmas on this finite set is not equal to number of Latin squares. How to prove it?

Comment: I suppose you mean `magmas`?

Comment: @Bernard yes, thx)

Comment: @bof yes, I don't no, how I can named this tables of elements, just operation table?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001329

Comment: @bof groupoids = magma?

Comment: @bof I am not sure, that I understand how to use this site...

Comment: Groupoid is the traditional name for a set with a binary operation which is not required to satisfy anything except closure. Nowadays some people (especially category theorists) call them magmas because they use the name "groupoids" for something else. Anyway, the oeis sequence I linked to is the number of nonisomorphic binary operations on $n$ elements.

Comment: @bof okey, thx)

Comment: @bof your comment should be the (accepted) answer!

Comment: _I think that this is no real Latin square, but I don't know how to name it_: [**multiplication tables**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicationTable.html).